# Retrieving set of rows from database : "sql: expected 1 arguments, got 2"

Tags: mysql, go

I'm trying to retrieve a set of rows from the database. I'm mapping the struct which has 2 matching variables. However, golang throws the below error.

Error occurs when running `err = row.Scan(&resourceList)`

> s:"sql: expected 1 arguments, got 2"

```
type Permission struct {
    ID               int    `json:"id"`
    Name             string `json:"name"`
    Description      string `json:"description"`
    ParentResourceID int    `json:"parentResourceId"`
}

func GetResourcesByResourceTypeId(resourceTypeId string) ([]Permission, string, error) {
    db, ctx := db.GetDB()
    query := "CALL usp_GetParentResourceListByResourceTypeID(?)"
    var resourceList []Permission
    stmt, err := db.Prepare(query)
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorln("Error in preparing statement. " + err.Error())
        return nil, "Error in preparing statement.", err
    }
    defer stmt.Close()
    
    row := stmt.QueryRow(ctx, resourceTypeId)
    
    err = row.Scan(&resourceList)
    if err == nil {
        return resourceList, "Resource retrieval.", nil
    }
    
    log.Warningln("Resource retrieval failed, ResourceTypeID: " + resourceTypeId + ".")
    return resourceList, "Resource retrieval failed.", nil
}
```

SQL Returns below

```
ID  Name
15  Applications
16  Subscriptions
17  Payments
```

What seems to be the issue here?

Comment: Where exactly does the error occur?

Comment: Here `err = row.Scan(&resourceList)`

Comment: What does `usp_GetParentResourceListByResourceTypeID` return?

Comment: Mentioned in the question. See the latter part

Comment: unrelated but relevant `defer stmt.Close()` should be before the error handling, or you will have an un closed connection when you have errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Stmt.QueryRow`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Stmt.QueryRow) should only be passed the arguments to be filled into the prepared statement. Since you're passing `ctx` as the first argument, it is trying to fill in both `ctx` and `resourceTypeId` into the prepared statement. That is why you are seeing "**expected 1 arguments, got 2**". Your statement should only take one argument, and you are giving two.

If you want to use the context in the query, use instead [`Stmt.QueryRowContext`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Stmt.QueryRowContext).

Comment: Now its throwing `s:
"sql: expected 2 destination arguments in Scan, not 1"`

Comment: This is a separate issue in itself, but the error message should perhaps be self explanatory. You can use [`Row.Columns`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Rows.Columns) if you are unsure what / how many values are in the row. As explained in [`Row.Scan`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Rows.Scan), "**The number of values in dest must be the same as the number of columns in Rows.**"